# get html table in asp.net mvc controller without ajax call

Tags: html, model-view-controller, html-table, controller, formcollection

I am creating a web in in which I have a table,

```
<table>
   @foreach (var test in Model.testingdata)
   {
       <tr>
            <td>
                 <input type="hidden" name="testSpan @i" value="@test.ID" />
            </td>
       </tr>
   }
</table>
```

I want to get the data of this table in my mvc controller without any ajax call

what is a way of getting the data in my controller

Comment: When you say mvc controller, what are you using on your server side? Is it a restful api with json endpoints or some kind of serverside html rendering which just gets returned and displayed, or something different?

Comment: @SamCosta1 the data of the table will be stored in a list and i am using entity to store the data in my table

Comment: I'm assuming this is a list that exists server side? But what is your sever side? By the terms you're using I'm guessing you're using the spring framework?

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc

Comment: So the only way you can get data from your server without making an ajax call is for the data to in the page on the initial load. i.e. the server builds up the HTML of the table with all the data.

Do you do this kind of thing anywhere else in your application?

Comment: @SamCosta1 no i never did this

Comment: That's the only real option you've got if you don't want to make api calls. Could you post a snippet of code from your server, where you are serving data from at the moment?

Comment: I think i did not explain to you properly i am editing the question again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood in the comments, I thought you were trying to render data rather than post it back to the server.

To do this without javascript or ajax you could post the data as a form.

For this you should wrap your table in a form element. For example

```
<form action="/post-location" method="post">
  <table> .... </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you click the submit button it will post the data to the location specified in the 'action' field.

See this example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp